# How to get username from an url after matching url with a particular string?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get username from an url after checking the rest of url is similar to a string.

For eg : I need username from the url 'http://mysite.com/username' . before that need to check

site url as 'http://mysite.com/' and also username part contains only alphabets,numbers,

underscore and periods..

How is it possible using php?

Comment: Dif you try anything? Do you have ideas to do that?

Comment: @Shoban : ya tried with preg_match.. but it shows error..

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: @Adrian : Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: preg_match('/http://mysite.com//[a-zA-Z0-9-]', $user_name, $matches); @navnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with PHP5.4.5:

```
<?php

$simple = 'http://mysite.com/username';

if ( preg_match('/http:\/\/mysite\.com\/(?:([-\w]+)\/?)/', $simple, $match) > 0){
    echo 'Username is: '.$match[1] . "\n";

}

$complex = 'http://mysite.com.zzz.yyy/john/';
if ( preg_match('/http:\/\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*\/(?:([-\w]+)\/?)/', $complex, $match) > 0){
    echo 'Username is: '.$match[1] . "\n";

}

?>
```

output:

```
Username is: username
Username is: john
```

Answer (score 1):

There are functions for parsing URLs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

If you do this:

```
$url = 'http://mysite.com/username';
$array = parse_url($url);
print_r($array);
```

You will see this:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => mysite.com
    [path] => /username
)
```

now you can treat the path of the URL seperately. If there's more to it than just `/username/` then you would split on '/' and use the first item returned.

```
    $path_array = explode('/',$array['path']);
```

Comment: I downvoted because your answer linked to the function but didn't explain how to use it or do anything to actually answer his question really, if you ammend your answer I'll be happy to remove my downvote and upvote if it deserves so.

Comment: OK then, I've added a full explanation.

Comment: Modified my vote appropriately, thanks for creating a much better answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this with regex, you can use a pattern with two capture groups, one for the domain name and one for the username, like so:

```
^http\:\/\/([^/]+)\/(.+)$
```

(I escaped the colon there because I honestly can't remember off the top of my head whether or not it's necessary.  If not, it doesn't need the escape character)

This will look for http:// followed by a string that doesn't contain a / (so it'll keep grabbing until it reaches the next /) and then expects a / and then grabs anything else that follows up until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
preg_match('/mysite.com//[a-zA-Z0-9-]';, $user_name, $matches);
```

You have no delimiter, and what's with the `;`? Try this:

```
preg_match('|/mysite.com//[a-zA-Z0-9-]|', $user_name, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/username";
$arr = parse_url($url);
if($arr['host'] != "mysite.com"){
    // do something 
}
print_r(trim($arr['path'],'/'));
```